# Jquery post not working in IE 8 or earlier

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery, post, internet-explorer-8

So this function works in all other browsers except IE. I only have access to IE 8 so can't say if newer versions work or not. I don't have access to the PHP or how it's calling the SQL DB, so I can't say for sure it's the javascript. The alert never gets triggered in IE.

```
$.post( 'http://foo/geo/getGeoResultsByGeoId.php', {geoId: 1}, function(data){
alert('inside');        
    var DBinfo = $.parseJSON(data);
    if(DBinfo.data.length == sites.length) {
        for (var i=0; i<sites.length; i++) {
            sites[i].votesUp = Number(DBinfo.data[i].votesUp);
            sites[i].votesDown = Number(DBinfo.data[i].votesDown);
            sites[i].mag = getMagnitude(Number(DBinfo.data[i].votesUp), Number(DBinfo.data[i].votesDown));
            createGraph(sites[i]);
        }
        setMarkers(map, sites);
     }
});
```

Comment: why do you have 2 success functions?

Comment: as @wirey stated, you don't need .success() if you're using the call back, since the callback is a .success() essentially. choose one or the other.

Comment: @kennypu: Sounds like an answer to me....

Comment: @WesleyMurch I'm not sure whether both functions will run or not, and how it works in different browsers so I won't post that as an answer :)

Comment: sorry, that was left over from me trying to debug. Doesn't make any difference in IE whether in success or or not, still broken :(

Comment: If you alert(data) instead of alert('inside'); what do you see?

Comment: nothing in IE, any other browser I'll get JSON object that's like this but a 100 or more entries  {"data":[{"name":"Brian Kelly","votesUp":"3","votesDown":"2"},{"name":"Rich Ellerson","votesUp":"0","votesDown":"0"},{"name":"Bronco Mendenhall","votesUp":"0","votesDown":"0"},{"name":"Ken Niumatalolo","votesUp":"1","votesDown":"0"},{"name":"Jimbo Fisher","votesUp":"0","votesDown":"0"},{"name":"Dabo Swinney","votesUp":"1","votesDown":"2"},{"name":"Dave Doeren","votesUp":"2","votesDown":"0"}]}

Comment: @user1310774 Is this a cross-domain request? IE doesn't support CORS in the same way modern browsers do. (it requires using a different object to send the request, which is not supported by jQuery.)

Comment: yes it's a cross-domain request. What's the solution without jQuery?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery $.post() + IE8](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6845150/1699210)

Answer (score 1):

Put this line within your HTML just after the <`head`> tag starts

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

It will work for `IE8+`.

Along with this, do not forget to mention the data type in your `$.post` request. You can do this as

```
    $.post(url, 
    function(){
     //your content here
    },'dataType')
    .fail(function(jqXHR,status)
    {
    });
```

**dataType** can be `xml`, `json`, `text`, or `jsonp` or a combination of datatypes. So, choose as per your datatype and it'll work fine. It worked for me at least, don't know if I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I expect the issue is the timing of the two different success callbacks. This should work:

```
$.post( 'http://fooURL/getGeoResultsByGeoId.php', {geoId: 1}, function(data){
    alert('inside');
    var DBinfo = $.parseJSON(data);
    if(DBinfo.data.length == sites.length) {
      for (var i=0; i<sites.length; i++) {
        sites[i].votesUp = Number(DBinfo.data[i].votesUp);
        sites[i].votesDown = Number(DBinfo.data[i].votesDown);
        sites[i].mag = getMagnitude(Number(DBinfo.data[i].votesUp),    Number(DBinfo.data[i].votesDown));
        createGraph(sites[i]);
      }
      setMarkers(map, sites);
    }
});
```

Comment: sorry, that double success was just left over from me trying basically anything and everything to get it to work. Same issue with everything in one success.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this instead if your return data is JSON and your making a cross domain request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://fooURL/getGeoResultsByGeoId.php?callback=?',
    data : {geoId: 1},
    dataType : 'JSONP',
    success: function(data) {
        DBinfo = data;
        alert('inside');
        if(DBinfo.data.length == sites.length) {
            for (var i=0; i<sites.length; i++) {
                sites[i].votesUp = Number(DBinfo.data[i].votesUp);
                sites[i].votesDown = Number(DBinfo.data[i].votesDown);
                sites[i].mag = getMagnitude(Number(DBinfo.data[i].votesUp), Number(DBinfo.data[i].votesDown));
                createGraph(sites[i]);
            }

            setMarkers(map, sites);
         }
    },
    type : 'POST' 
});
```

Comment: sorry, that double success was just left over from me trying basically anything and everything to get it to work. Same issue with everything in one success.

Comment: @user1310774 Also can you provide a **sample** of the `JSON` your parsing?

Comment: you were missing a "," after dataType, but yea that $.ajax isn't working either.

Comment: the JSON looks like this

{"data":[{"name":"Brian Kelly","votesUp":"3","votesDown":"2"},{"name":"Rich Ellerson","votesUp":"0","votesDown":"0"}]}

Comment: What do you get if you change alert('inside'); to alert(data);

Comment: in IE the alert is never triggered , in any other browser i get [object Object]

Comment: I think we would need to see a work site or the full code, it is most likely a piece of code above the ajax call that is breaking in IE

Comment: @user1310774 Give my updated answer a try, since you said your making a cross domain request you need to use something like `JSONP`